# Why doesn't r.null convert -3.4e+38 to nodata?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, nodata

I have a raster with nodata values of 3.4028e+38. I want to convert the nodata to be -32768, so it is consistent with the nodata values of some other layers. I found a thread on here that indicated r.null was the best way to convert, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Why?

I am using QGIS 3.22.

Here is the raster I want to convert. Note the nodata value. :
[image]

Then, I pass the file and the information to r.null:
[image]

This is the output. It sets the minimum value to the value I wanted to be reserved for nodata. And then there's no nodata value at all. Why?

Sometimes it will convert to nodata, but the value will be listed as 'nan' which is not the intended value.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, 3.4028e+38 is NOT nodata. Also -32768 is not nodata. Some GIS software arbitrarily assign some very large or very small value to represent nodata. However some GIS software actually have a "nodata" representation in their raster format. The module that you mentioned, `r.null` is a GRASS GIS module. And in GRASS there is a true nodata (i.e. null) in the raster format. You can, using the `r.null` utility, choose to convert some value to null in the GRASS internal representation:

```
 r.null map=<your GRASS raster> setnull=3.4028e+38
```

Alternatively, if you have true null values in the raster, with the same module you can assign those pixels some (arbitrary) value, so:

```
r.null map=<your GRASS raster> null=-32768
```

Those two commands should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in the raster calculator:
if(raster== (-3.40282*10^38), null(), raster)

if the decimals are an issue:
if(raster<= (-3.40282*10^38), null(), raster)